# FMod, Multisound Module not looping in game

Tags: fmod

I am currently trying to implement a simple soundtrack in the Unity3D Angry Bots Demo using FMod. I created an event with a Multisound Event, containing 2 loops a 16 Bars. The event is 16bars long and inside a Loop Region. I set the the Module to loop (not the individual loops) and the Playlist mode to random. When I trigger the the event from inside Unity3D using .play() the event plays, but after 32 bars there's silence. After a while the module starts playing again. I Believe the module waits a couple of bars before it triggers another loop. I have Quantization set to tempo (though I think that makes no difference in my case).

Are Multisound events the right way to go - or am I missing something else?